# How to correctly bound to a class with inheritance

Tags: c#, xaml, inheritance, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a treeview. In the treeview I have Student - Homework
The Homework is a Class with Hineritance, so under Homerwork I have -> ScienceH, PhysicsH, MathH
How can I create a XAML that is bound to the Homework list but changes depending on the "child" specifics?

I'm blocked as I do not understand how to do the binding

```
class Student
    {
        public string Name;
        List<Homework> homeworks;
    }

class Homework
    {
        public DateTime Date;
        public int Vote;
    }
class ScienceH : Homework
    {
        public string Topic;
    }
class PhysicsH : Homework
    {
        public int Points;
    }
```

I expect to have an item that shows the additional fields depending on which child they have

Comment: For binding, your properties are missing change notification. As for the UI, I like type Targetting Data Templates for this. About 6 years ago I wrote a intro into MVVM, wich should get you up to speed. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm

Comment: Correct, I need to define IList and raise property changes. My issue was more on how the XAML should be done to do the binding. I need that as I'm not very good on XAML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a `TreeView` in UWP XAML like this, as detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view):

```xml
<TreeView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ListOfStudents}">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Student">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind homeworks}"
                          Content="{x:Bind Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

You would then need to define a `DataTemplate` for each of class you expect to display. Add this in your `TreeView` XAML:

```xml
<TreeView.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:ScienceH">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vote}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:PhysicsH ">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Date}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vote}" />
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Points}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</TreeView.Resources>
```

You can also read more on the `DataTemplate` class [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate).

Note that, as suggested in the comments, you need to implement change notifications in your classes to ensure correct binding. This is all detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth).

Alternatively, you seem to have a `TreeView` with a tree structure of known, fixed depth: depth 0 would be the list of `Student` and depth 1 would be the list of `Homework`, so you could also do without `TreeView` and simply nest two `ItemsControl` within one another.

Comment: Amazing, Sounds very good! In reality I have more levels below that, this is why I was looking for a treeview :)

Comment: You should probably try before accepting the answer though :p

Comment: hehehe you mean it will not work ??? hehehehe I think it will work and if I get stuck I'll come back with the real, full code :). Thank you a lot for your help

Comment: I've never done UWP and I havn't tried my code so I'm not sure. But I can edit as mush as needed. I'm more of a WPF guy

Comment: Nice to see that I am not the only one that sees the power of Templates targetted a ViewModel type :)

Comment: Oh but that's the whole point of templates! I think you're *supposed* to target ViewModel types. In this case there seem to be a confusion between model and view model but anyway